# What language was Xcode written in?

Tags: xcode, ide

Any clue which language Xcode IDE is written in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ (ordered *alphabetically*). Omitting external tools Xcode serves as a front end for and libraries which are not unique to the Xcode toolkit, I don't know of other languages they use in the app itself. This is also the norm for other related apps (e.g. Instruments).

The current version uses Garbage Collection for Objective-C and Objective-C++.

External components such as Clang and Xcode's indexer are written predominantly in C++.

Comment: I for one am very curious how much Objective-C++ is actually used in Xcode. I suspect not much, if any. But it's certainly used elsewhere, and this is a great answer.

Comment: @Steven Although they use C++ (mostly the lower levels), I don't think they are using much ObjC++, favoring to set up translation fences where appropriate (perhaps because ObjC++ takes so long to compile). Even OS X's 'autorelease pools' are implemented with C++. There's also a good amount of C++ behind the scenes in everyday technologies, CoreAnimation, CoreGraphics, Garbage Collection, WebKit, the objc runtime, etc... In that sense, I'd say our suspicions are close.

Comment: How do you know that Xcode was built using C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++?

Comment: @WonixerA Sample it while it is doing something and assess the symbol names. Xcode no longer uses Garbage Collection. My answer here is now quite old BTW.

Comment: @WonixerA C symbols are usually names without parameters. C++ symbols include parameters and types and often have two leading underscores and sometimes two consecutive colons. ObjC symbols are easy to spot because of the brackets. C++ symbols called from ObjC are generally in ObjC++ translations. I could go on but that illustrates it at a high level.

Comment: There's a decent amount of Swift in Xcode these days for many of the newer features.

Answer (score 1):

I second the guess, most likely Objective-C since all the Cocoa frameworks link natively. GNUstep's Gorm (Interface Builder lookalike) is certainly written in Objective-C http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorm_(computing). Curiously, though, it appears that NeXTStep's Interface Builder was originally written in Lisp if Wikipedia is to be believed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder.